# Why some of the Tampermonkey userscript have BLUE switch?

Tags: tampermonkey

When I add some userscripts to Tampermonkey, I see some of the Userscripts have "BLUE" switch. See below screenshot. What's that mean?

[image]

Comment: It's a `@run-at context-menu` userscript.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you! Can you put this to "Answer"?